# Create an array with the maximum of a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I've 24 arrays in a list and I'd like to crate an array with the maximum of each index.

In other words, I've something like this

```
list_value = [array([1,2,3]), array([4,5,6]), array([7,8,9]), array([1,5,8]), array([9,4,3])]
```

In my case, each array has 280000 values.

And I would like create an array like this:

```
max_value = [array([max(4,4,7,1,9),max(2,5,8,5,4),max(3,6,9,8,3)])]
```

So I want to finally obtain:

```
max_value = [9,8,9]
type(max_value) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `list_value` to a NumPy array and then apply [`numpy.ndarray.max`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html) on 0th axis:

```
>>> arr = np.array(list_value)
>>> arr.max(axis=0)
array([9, 8, 9])
```